# Adding Username login to Devise in Rails 4 - Error creating User

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, pundit

Login works fine after following this guide: [Allow users to sign in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

However creating a new User does no longer work. This is what I am getting:

```
Started POST "/users" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-07-30 15:08:49 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by UsersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"user", "account_id"=>"1", "username"=>"user", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
  Account Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (2.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('user') LIMIT 1
   (2.0ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 847ms (ActiveRecord: 14.2ms)
```

I have no idea why it's not working. Here is some of the code involved with devise:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me, :account_id) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end


  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = "Access denied."
    redirect_to (request.referrer || root_path)
  end
end
```

user_controller.rb :

```
def create
@account = Account.find(params[:user][:account_id])
@user = @account.users.build(user_params)
authorize @user
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Successfully created User' }
    format.js {}
  end
end

private
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:role, :name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account_id)
end
```

user.rb :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :expenses

  validates :username, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  attr_accessor :login

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?


  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["username = :value OR lower(email) = lower(:value)", { :value => login }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end
end
```

I believe the error comes from this `find_for_database_authentication` method

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The 'user exists' in the error log just before the rollback might suggest that there is already a user called 'user' in the database. Did you mean to call the user 'user'?

Comment: @AFaderDarkly thank you for your answer. Yes, I called the user 'user' for testing purposes but whatever I call it I get the same `User Exists` error.